# How do I use COM reference within SSIS package?

Tags: com, ssis, gac

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation` COM object library (*C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll*) from within an SSIS Script Task to manipulate .zip archives.

Unfortunately, although I have successfully added the relevant Reference and the Script Task compiles OK. I'm using VB.NET, for what it's worth. I get the following runtime error as soon as I try to create any objects defined within the library:

> Error: 0x1 at Archive File: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Shell32, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Interop.Shell32, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>      at ST_a2650b7f39504eaa8c80e37a6736d957.vbproj.ScriptMain.Main()

I thought the Interop DLL would all be taken care of for me - does anyone know what step am I missing?

Comment: Why not try it with 7zip?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net

Comment: Unfortunately I need the solution I'm trying to develop to work without 3rd party software :-(

Comment: Do I need to install the Interop.Shell32 assembly into the GAC?  If so, where can I download gacutil from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS needs all .dll references to be registered with the GAC, you are correct.

You have different options regarding installing this dll into the GAC:

1. Drag and drop the .dll into the **%windir%\assembly\** folder.
2. Use the **gacutil.exe** you are thinking about using: Regarding installing into the GAC using the gacutil, there is alot of useful information here: [**Global_Assembly_Cache**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). Basically, if you have the .NET framework installed (you are using VB.NET so no problem there), you will have a gacutil.exe in your Microsoft.NET folder.
3. (What I normally use when all else fails) Create a windows MSI project in Visual Studio that automatically does all this for you, *useful info here*: [**How to install assembly in the GAC using MSI**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1496141.aspx/1)

If you install that .dll in the GAC and you are still having problems, another option is to actually create a separate visual studio project that contains your logic for manipulating the needed zip files build it and call its exe from SSIS using the **Execute Process Task**. You can pass arguments specified in the SSIS package. Not very elegant, but it gets the job done if you are keen on using SSIS.

---

#### UPDATE:

The solution in this question did the trick [SSIS Script Task COMException / FileNotFoundException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965210/ssis-script-task-comexception-filenotfoundexception-error?lq=1). The problem was in adding a signed reference of the dll, this answer provides a good step-by-step workaround for adding a COM reference within the SSIS Script Task.

Comment: What DLL do I need to put into the GAC? I've tried installing both "Interop.Shell32.dll" and "Shell32.dll", but neither worked.

When I try to install the Interop.Shell32.dll that SSIS generates in its temporary folder, I'm told it doesn't have a strong name. Installing Shell32.dll fails because the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: By the way, using Windows Explorer to install into the GAC via drag & drop doesn't work either, as I'm prevented from dropping files into the C:\Windows\assembly virtual folder (even when I run as adminstrator).

Comment: I had to install the .NET Framework SDK in order to get gacutil too.

Comment: Finally, unfortunately I can't explore go with your last suggestion as I don't have Visual Studio - only VSTA. :-(  I suppose I could install Visual Studio Express, but it's rather a lot of effort for a simple archiving problem!

Comment: By the way, I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 - so System.IO.Compression isn't an option either.

Comment: @JezWalters I looked around, try this out (steps 2-10 of the answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965210/ssis-script-task-comexception-filenotfoundexception-error

Comment: When I tried adding the Shell32 reference without having the project signed, it added an unsigned reference as well. The trouble is getting that signed Interop.Shell32.dll

Comment: Good grief what a lot of hassle - but it worked in the end!  Many thanks for your peseverance.

Comment: Don't mention it, safe to say that it is not the most intuitive of functionalities. Glad it worked though!