# SSIS - Reference DLL Dynamic Directory

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to create some Crystal Reports via SSIS which works wonderfully when it can find the DLLs, but not so much when it can't.

I've gone into the package to add the references, but the problem is when the package is running from SQL Agent it can't find the references since they aren't in that drive path.

Is it possible to put the DLL files in separate locations that can be accessed independently and have the path to the DLLs be stored in a variable and then referenced either programmatically or have the path defined dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: Adding the assemblies to the GAC did not work? Tried that?

Answer (score 1):

All DLL references used in SSIS need to be registered with the **GAC**.

You have a couple of different options to do that, check out my previous answer for the how: [How do I use COM reference within SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127549/how-do-i-use-com-reference-within-ssis-package/13139252#13139252)

Comment: Do they need to be registered on each machine that the package will be running from (dev, uat, prod, etc.)?

Comment: are you sure this is 100% true the only way to do this? Normal .net apps can have a bin search path as well. Does DTSEXEC not follow this as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could try copying the DLLs to the SQL Server binary folder (in my case "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\binn").

I had this problem calling a .Net library that uses HtmlUnit. The NuGet version I'm using doesn't have a Strong Name, and so can't be GACed, but that worked for me.